# Write multiple dataframes to separate .csv file in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am new to python. I am sure there is simple way to do this but I am struggling a bit.
I have 100 dataframes with names `Lens1`,`Lens2`, ..., `Lens100`.
I want to write each dataframe to a csv file.

`Lens1.to_csv(path+"lens 1.csv", index=False)` This command for `Lens2` and Lens2.csv... and so on till `Lens100` save as Lens100.csv. so a 100 times...

I have tried the following:

```
for key,j in range(101):
    x='Lens%s'%(j)
    x.to_csv(path+x+".csv")
```

It does not seem to work and the error is

> 'str' object has no attribute 'to_csv'.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Not generally recommended, but if you have a dataframe `Lens1`, you can access it from the string as `df = eval("Lens1")` then `df.to_csv()` etc

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the `x` in your `for` loop are not dataframes, but strings. You cannot call a dataframe by adding a `str` to its name; Python will consider it as a string.

You can store the dataframes in a list `dataframes` first, then store the names of the dataframes in a list `name`. Then, proceed using the following codes.

```py
for j in range(101):
    x = dataframes[j]
    x.to_csv(path + name[j] + ".csv", index = False)
```